# Prove that $ \frac{1}{x^{n+1}}f^{(n)}(1/x) = (-1)^n\frac{d^n}{dx^n}[x^{n-1}f(1/x)]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Prove that
>   $$ \frac{1}{x^{n+1}}f^{(n)}(1/x) = (-1)^n\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left[x^{n-1}f(1/x)\right] $$
>   where $(n)$ denotes the $n$th derivative.

PS: $f$ is continuous on $(-\infty, +\infty)$ and $x \ne 0$.

Comment: I'm not sure, but $1/x$  is not continuous, so that may be not a legit function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This result can be proven using induction. First derive the identity

$$\frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}}\left[x^{(n+1)-1}f(1/x)\right] = \left(x\frac{d}{dx} + (n+1)\right) \frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}\left[x^{n-1}f(1/x)\right]$$
using the [general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) with $u(x) = x$ and $v(x) = x^{n-1}f(1/x)$. Now assume the result holds for $n$, i.e. 
$$\frac{1}{x^{n+1}} f^{(n)}(1/x) = (-1)^n \frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}\left[x^{n-1}f(1/x)\right]$$
and apply the operator $\left(x\frac{d}{dx} + (n+1)\right)$ to both sides of this equation. Simplify the right hand side using the product rule and use the identity above to simply the right hand side. What you are left with should be the result for $n+1$. It then just remains to check the base-case $n=1$.

Comment: How did you work out that contradiction statement of deleted answer?